# Liferay welcome theme Navigation bar

Tags: html, css, sass, themes, liferay-6

I am trying to change size Page titles. But I am not able change it.

I have found CSS for nav bar in custom.css as below:

```
#navigation {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;

    li {
        border: solid #E2E3E3;
        border-width: 0 1px;
        display: none;
        /* WIDTH:33.333%; */    

        &:first-child {
            border-left-width: 0;
        }
     }
}
```

Although, width is commented or removed from li, I am seeing width of nav bar 33.333% only.

What is that I am missing? Can someone  help me?

Thanks for your help!

Here is how my page's nav bar look alike:

[image]

Comment: Are you certain the width information is coming from *those* rules?  There's no other location where width is being set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Liferay's welcome theme come with sas compilation. Inside compiled CSS, you need to change properties of CSS and then those will be accepted as final values.